# Why is my Send only bus not creating a temporary queue?

Tags: masstransit

For testing a request/respond saga with masstransit I created an console application to initiate the saga by sending a message on the bus (RabbitMQ).

According to the [documentation](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/gotchas.html#send-only-bus) the console application does not need to have any endpoints defined to receive the response.

I create the bus with the following code:

```
            context.Bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            IRabbitMqHost host = x.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
        });
```

When the above code runs, I am not seeing any exchanges or a temporary queue being created.

Sending the request will result will result in executing the saga but the responds will never come back to the original sender and a timeout exception will be thrown.

Sending the request:

```
    public async Task Test(TestContext context)
    {
        var triggerRequestMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TriggerRequestMessage>Messages.MFAMessages.ValidMessage);

        var client = CreateRequestClient(context);
        var response = await client.Request(triggerRequestMessage);
        Logger.Log("Result: PublishMFAMessage");
    }

    IRequestClient<TriggerRequestMessage, ResponseMessage> CreateRequestClient(TestContext context)
    {
        var serviceAddress = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/MTTest/SAGAS_AUTHBOLTON");
        var client = context.Bus.CreateRequestClient<TriggerRequestMessage, ResponseMessage>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        return client;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the temporary not being created?

Comment: Are you binding any consumers? Nothing really happens until there's someone listening for a message.

Comment: Hi @travis tnx for your reply. According to the documentation that is not needed: If you need to only send or publish messages, **don’t create any receive endpoints**. The bus **will automatically create a temporary queue** for the bus which can be used to publish events, as well as send commands and do request/response conversations. The temporary is not being created.

Comment: This service may not bind any consumers, but you need something listening. So does another service listen? It's the listener that binds all the stuff together.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the above code didn't create any private consumer was because I wan't starting the Bus. duhhh!!

The code that was missing:

```
context.Bus.Start();
```

@travis thanks for the help!

Comment: Also be sure to call Stop when your process exits, or you might leave some background behavior unfinished!